# Can you create an R function that calls using a prefix and suffix (operating like brackets)?

Tags: r, function

I have read about [prefix functions and infix functions](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#special-calls) on Hadley Wickham's Advanced R website.  I would like to know if there is any way to define functions that are called by placing a prefix and suffix around a single argument, so that the prefix and suffix operate like brackets.  **Is there any way to create a function like this, and if so, how do you do it?**

---

**An example for formulation:** In order to give a specific example for formulation, suppose you have an object `char` that is a character string.  You want to create a function that is called on a character string using the prefix `_#` and suffix `#_` and the function adds five dashes to the front of the character string.  If programmed successfully, it would operate as shown below.

```
char
[1] "Hello"

_#char#_
[1] "-----Hello"
```

Comment: No. Something like `_#char#_` would not even pass the parsing stage. You would not be able to add such a function built on prefix/suffixes in R. The only wau to make new infix operators is with the `%%` syntax. Everything else should be proper functions.

Comment: @MrFlick is right, the parser is the limitation here. Ben, what problem are you addressing that this functionality would offer a unique solution?

Comment: @r2evans: Nothing special --- just want to program a function that reformats an object in a certain way, and figured it would be nice to have a simple "bracket" type syntax to call it.  I can use a regular prefix function if there is no way to do this.

Comment: You can write your own parser.  R has 3 or so:  R code, Rd files, LaTeX code.  The latter two are in the `tools` package, the R parser is in `src/main/gram.y` in the sources.

Comment: @user2554330 But how would you use that in R? Are you recommending compiling your own version of R from source code with a non-standard parser?

Comment: @MrFlick:  I guess you'd use it like `tools::parseRd()` or `tools::parseLatex()`:  you have an input file in your new language which is somewhat R-like, and you parse it using your parser, then evaluate it in the usual way (assuming the output matches the R parser output).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a way to do this as long as your special operator takes a particular form, that is `.%_% char %_%.` . This is because the parser will interpret the dot as a variable name. If we use non-standard evaluation, we don't need the dot to actually exist, and we only need to use this as a marker for opening and closing our special operator. So we can do something like this:

```r
`%_%` <- function(a, b) 
{
   if((deparse(match.call()$a) != ".") +
      (deparse(match.call()$b) != ".") != 1)
     stop("Unrecognised SPECIAL")
   
  if(deparse(match.call()$a == "."))
    return(`attr<-`(b, "prepped", TRUE))
  
  if(attr(a, "prepped"))
    return(paste0("-----", a))
  
  stop("Unrecognised SPECIAL")
}

.%_% "hello" %_%.
#> [1] "-----hello"
```

However, this is a weird thing to do in R. It's not idiomatic and uses more keystrokes than a simple function call would. It would also very likely cause unpredictable problems in places where non-standard evaluation is used. This is really just a demo to show that it *can* be done. Not that it *should* be done.

Answer (score 3):

Writing a simple function seems like a more R-like solution. If terseness is a priority, then maybe something like

```
._ <- function(x) paste0("-----", x)

._("hello")
# [1] "-----hello"
```

Or if you wanted something more bracket-like

```
.. <- structure(list(NULL), class="dasher")
`[.dasher` <- function(a, x) paste0("-----", x)

..["hello"]
# [1] "-----hello"
```

Another way to use a custom class would be to redefine the `-` operator to paste that value in front of the string. For example

```
literal <- function(x) {class(x)<-"literal"; x}
`-.literal` <- function(e1, e2) {literal(paste0("-", unclass(e1)))}
print.literal <- function(x) print(unclass(x))
```

Then you can do

```
val <- literal("hello")
-----val
# [1] "-----hello"
---val
# [1] "---hello"
```

So here the number of `-` you type is the number you get in the output.

You can get creative/weird with syntax, but you need to make sure whatever symbols you come up with can be parsed by the parser otherwise you are out-of-luck.

Comment: I should have mentioned in my answer that it's not something I would ever actually use - just a demo of creative use of syntax that gets past the parser. I guess you get +1 for being sensible!

Comment: @AllanCameron I don’t know if I’d call this solution sensible. I’d still argue for a proper readable function name. But your solution gets points for creativity for sure.